# ../@types/mongodb/index.d.ts:35:18 - error TS2724: '"bson"' has no exported member named 'ObjectID'. Did you mean 'ObjectId'?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, types, bson

Getting this error. my typescript version is 4.5.4 and  "@types/mongodb": "~3.3.1",
"@types/mongoose": "~5.5.17". any idea how to solve

```
../@types/mongodb/index.d.ts:49:74 - error TS2724: '"bson"' has no exported member named 'ObjectID'. Did you mean 'ObjectId'?

49 export { Binary, DBRef, Decimal128, Double, Int32, Long, MaxKey, MinKey, ObjectID, ObjectId, Timestamp } from 'bson';
                                                                            ~~~~~~~~

  ../bson/bson.d.ts:939:22
    939 export declare class ObjectId extends BSONValue {
                             ~~~~~~~~
    'ObjectId' is declared here.
```

Comment: I wonder if the error is generated by some code that is executed.  I wonder if that code was written by you.  I wonder if it might help if you shared that code so others might identify the problem.

Answer (score 4):

This is because using bson 5.0.0 removed ObjectID which breaks everything that referenced it before. Force your program to use bson 4.7.2.

Answer (score 4):

For future reference for others struggling with the same error.

The best way of resolving the error is to upgrade the `mongodb` package to version 4.x.x or newer and drop the need for the `@types/mongodb` package that require the `@types/bson` package.

If the above is not a viable solution to you, run the `npm ls bson` command. You should see something like:

```
├─┬ @types/mongodb@3.6.7
│ └─┬ @types/bson@4.2.0
│   └── bson@5.4.0
└─┬ mongodb@3.6.3
  └── bson@1.1.6
```

It is likely the deprecated `@types/bson@4.2.0` package that is messing with you.

Create an override for the `@types/bson` package and downgrade to version `4.0.5` which is the latest version other than `4.2.0`.

In you `package.json`:

```
"overrides": {
        "@types/mongodb": {
            "@types/bson": "4.0.5"
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Downgrading to version 6.8.3 solved the problem for me .I think there might be a bug with the current version of mongoose. Or the current version has compatibility issues with some of its dependencies .

Answer (score 1):

First, to address "@types/mongoose": [Mongoose added types to it's code base as of 5.11.0](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#5110--2020-11-30). So if you are using a version of Mongoose that's 5.11.0 or newer, you can remove that dependency.

The root cause here traces back to the `@types/mongodb` package, which contains what can be considered a bug in the dependencies. Namely, it allows any version of `@types/bson` to fulfill the dependency:

```json
    "dependencies": {
        "@types/bson": "*",
        "@types/node": "*"
    }
```

But in fact, it only supports specific versions `bson`. For those experiencing this error, `@types/mongodb` is trying re-export `ObjectID` from `bson`, like this:

```
export { Binary, DBRef, Decimal128, Double, Int32, Long, MaxKey, MinKey, ObjectID, ObjectId, Timestamp } from 'bson';
```

But [`ObjectID` was removed from `bson` in 5.0 of the module.](https://github.com/mongodb/js-bson/blob/main/docs/upgrade-to-v5.md#capital-d-objectid-export-removed)

Because of this situation, tools like `yarn` and `npm` can end up installing broken combinations of dependencies.

To resolve the issue, you have a choice of downgrading *or* upgrading the mongoose/mongodb/bson stack and their types so that they all agree on the same `bson` API.

The `npm ls` tool is useful to review what versions of each you have installed. AKA: `npm ls bson`.

You may find it useful to use the `overrides` feature with `yarn` or the `resolutions` feature of `npm` to force the resolution of a dependency to a specific version.

Answer (score 0):

My solution

```
npm i -D @types/mongodb@3.1.17

npm i bson@4.7.2 --save
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I just upgraded to `@types/bson@4.2.0` and the complain disappeared.